# Django REST Framework ObtainAuthToken User Login Api view

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello Django community,

I want to send back the email and the id of the user alongside the token when the user authenticate. I guess I must change the UserLoginApiView class but I don't know how to override the ObtainAuthToken class to do that.

Does anybody have suggestions it would be very helpful?

```
class UserLoginApiView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Handle creating user authentication tokens"""
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

This is my entire code on Github: https://github.com/KrestouferT/profiles-rest-api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens) it tell that you can override the return response of the post request in ObtainAuthToken:

> If you need a customized version of the obtain_auth_token view, you
> can do so by subclassing the ObtainAuthToken view class, and using
> that in your url conf instead.
>
> For example, you may return additional user information beyond the
> token value:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })
```

And in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', CustomAuthToken.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Is there a way to register this class to settings instead of routing it directly ?

Comment: @EbramShehata i don't think there a way as of right now as this is a prebuilt method from drf, they also don't provide a hook from the setting for the jwt response yet